# What is class Random seeded with when no seed is provided?

Tags: c#, .net, random

Class `Random` can be instantiated using a [constructor without parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx) and MSDN says that in this case it is seeded with some time-dependent value.

Is the way to derive that time-dependent value documented anywhere? Can I reproduce it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not documented, and I think that's on purpose. I don't see any good reason why something like this should be documented and the framework implementers should be able to choose how exactly to do this.

But if you want to know how does it work currently, just use ildasm or Reflector. Reflector will give you this (.Net 4.5 beta):

```
public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount)
{
}
```

If you look at [the source code of mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Random.cs#L48), you will see that since 2003, it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I still don't get *why* they use so bad seeding, and refuse to improve it.

Comment: Because this(and a few more issues) make it hard to use `System.Random` in a robust way. A significant part of all `Random` related questions on SO is due to this design flaw, so it's clearly a common source of errors that'd be easy to fix. Personally I dislike `System.Random` so much, that I wrote my own PRNG class that avoids these issues.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: To use `System.Random` in a robust and predictable way that will not change willy-nilly, just use your own mechanism to provide the seed. Don't depend on something subject to change and then complain that it is subject to change. (But yeah, they could probably have chosen a different method by now.)